# All calendar entries lost across iPhone 4, iPad, MacBook Air after iPhone upgraded to iOS 7. Help?

Tags: icloud, iphone, calendar, ical, ios

My husband has lost all his calendar entries after upgrading to iOS 7 on his iPhone earlier today. He deleted 3 football calendars from his iPhone as they were duplicated.  Everything was fine.  Now everything is gone, including on iCloud.

He has no back up elsewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any chance you can get professional support from Apple as part of AppleCare or a retail store? 5 minutes with a pro can work with you on all the places you might have a backup and understand if perhaps there is a chance to save the calendars.

Comment: "MacAir Book" ... just when I thought I've seen all the possible arrangements of 3 simple words, I'm proven wrong :p

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put both devices in offline mode (or power down the router) in case the duplicates were not really and the calendars were deleted.

You can use another computer (or a web browser) to log into iCloud.com and inspect the calendars as far as Apple sees things.

If the calendar data is still in the cloud, then your missing data is due to an error on each device or a temporary network condition.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked backups on your local machine?  iOS backups specifically. I have used [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm) to cherry pick lost data from past backups & restore to my iDevice.  Additionally, you could do a brute force restore from a backup to see if that brings it back.